# XPath for when no such element exist?

Tags: xml

I have this task with XML about books. I was asked to *Return all books provided on the condition that no book is priced at 7.5*

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <inventory>
    <book num="b1">
      <title>Snow Crash</title>
      <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
      <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
      <price>14.95</price>
      <chapter>
        <title>Snow Crash - Chapter A</title>
        <paragraph>
          This is the
          <emph>first</emph>
          paragraph.
          <image file="firstParaImage.gif"/>
          After image...
        </paragraph>
        <paragraph>
          This is the
          <emph>second</emph>
          paragraph.
          <image file="secondParaImage.gif"/>
          After image...
        </paragraph>
      </chapter>
      <chapter>
        <title>Snow Crash - Chapter B</title>
        <section>
          <title>Chapter B - section 1</title>
          <paragraph>
            This is the
            <emph>first</emph>
            paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
            <image file="Chapter_B_firstParaImage.gif"/>
            After image...
          </paragraph>
          <paragraph>
            This is the
            <emph>second</emph>
            paragraph of section 1 in chapter B.
            <image file="Chapter_B_secondParagraphImage.gif"/>
            After image...
          </paragraph>
        </section>
      </chapter>
      <chapter>
        <title>Chapter C</title>
        <paragraph>This chapter has no images and only one paragraph</paragraph>
      </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="b2">
      <title>Burning Tower</title>
      <author>Larry Niven</author>
      <author>Jerry Pournelle</author>
      <publisher>Pocket</publisher>
      <price>5.99</price>
      <chapter>
        <title>Burning Tower - Chapter A</title>
      </chapter>
      <chapter>
        <title>Burning Tower - Chapter B</title>
        <paragraph>
          This is the
          <emph>second</emph>
          paragraph of chapter B in the 2nd book.
          <image file="Burning_Tower_Chapter_B_secondParaImage.gif"/>
          After image...
        </paragraph>
      </chapter>
    </book>
    <book num="b3">
      <title>Zodiac</title>
      <author>Neal Stephenson</author>
      <publisher>Spectra</publisher>
      <price>7.50</price>
      <chapter>
        <title>Zodiac - Chapter A</title>
      </chapter>
    </book>
  </inventory>
```

**Because I do have a book which is priced `7.5`, I should get no books.**

When I tried this query, I got all the books that are not priced `7.5`, but this is not what I should get.  What am i missing?

```
//book[price!=7.50]/title/text()

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
Snow Crash
Burning Tower
</result>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
/inventory[not(book/price=7.50)]/book/title/text()
```

will return the `title` text of all `book`s provided no `book` in `inventory` has a `price` of `7.50`.